# Joining two pandas dataframes with custom sized intervals and aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have two data frames `df1` with two time series and `df2` with a set of intervals.

I want to join the two data frames preserving the index of df2  while resampling the time series with an aggregate function, let's say `max()`.

```
df1
Out[1]: 
                                           Y              X
timestamp                                                 
1900-01-01 00:00:10.679380200       0.581760      -0.282902
1900-01-01 00:00:10.720490500       0.581732      -0.282616
1900-01-01 00:00:10.762100500       0.578835      -0.281211
1900-01-01 00:00:10.801705300       0.547837      -0.277893
1900-01-01 00:00:10.846323700       0.543433      -0.277881
1900-01-01 00:00:10.889450100       0.538701      -0.279481
1900-01-01 00:00:10.894463800       0.538701      -0.279481
1900-01-01 00:00:10.896958800       0.538701      -0.279481
1900-01-01 00:00:10.897973300       0.536122      -0.278382
1900-01-01 00:00:10.924546500       0.536122      -0.278382
1900-01-01 00:00:10.936062400       0.536122      -0.278382
1900-01-01 00:00:10.980179700       0.536171      -0.278402
1900-01-01 00:00:11.021791100       0.541177      -0.279649
1900-01-01 00:00:11.059391200       0.549314      -0.280842
1900-01-01 00:00:11.104509400       0.559103      -0.281571
1900-01-01 00:00:11.147624400       0.569963      -0.282739
1900-01-01 00:00:11.187731700       0.572123      -0.282897
1900-01-01 00:00:11.227337100       0.574026      -0.283083
1900-01-01 00:00:11.268947200       0.574020      -0.283056
```

And df2

```
df2
Out[2]: 
                     start                     end
0  1970-01-01 00:00:10.140 1970-01-01 00:00:10.500
1  1970-01-01 00:00:10.700 1970-01-01 00:00:11.180
2  1970-01-01 00:00:11.320 1970-01-01 00:00:11.780
3  1970-01-01 00:00:11.930 1970-01-01 00:00:12.410
4  1970-01-01 00:00:12.500 1970-01-01 00:00:12.900
5  1970-01-01 00:00:13.080 1970-01-01 00:00:13.530
6  1970-01-01 00:00:13.700 1970-01-01 00:00:14.190
7  1970-01-01 00:00:14.310 1970-01-01 00:00:14.810
```

And the expected result:

```
df3:
                     start                     end    Ymax        Xmax
0  1970-01-01 00:00:10.140 1970-01-01 00:00:10.500          
1  1970-01-01 00:00:10.700 1970-01-01 00:00:11.180   0.581760   -0.27789
2  1970-01-01 00:00:11.320 1970-01-01 00:00:11.780   ...       ...
3  1970-01-01 00:00:11.930 1970-01-01 00:00:12.410   
4  1970-01-01 00:00:12.500 1970-01-01 00:00:12.900
5  1970-01-01 00:00:13.080 1970-01-01 00:00:13.530
6  1970-01-01 00:00:13.700 1970-01-01 00:00:14.190
7  1970-01-01 00:00:14.310 1970-01-01 00:00:14.810
```

I tried different things so far, but no solution found:

- df.resample() but it only takes fixed time frequencies
- df.join() adding a multiIndex and then grouping function.

Any idea?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do but the timestamp in `df1` corresponding to `Ymax = 0.581760` is `1900-01-01 00:00:10.679380200`, not `1970-...` like in `df2`. Is that a part of why your solution doesn't work?

Comment: The expected output is just a hand-written example. I am trying to demonstrate I would like the Y.max() and X.max() for each time interval e.g. for the interval 00:00:10.700 00:00:11.180. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Figured out how to do it without `itertuples`, and it's a simpler solution.

```
df1.index = df1.index + pd.DateOffset(years=70)

masked_df = [
    df1[(df2_start <= df1.index) & (df1.index <= df2_end)]
    for df2_start, df2_end in zip(df2['start'], df2['end'])
]

df2['Ymax'] = [np.max(df['Y']) if not df.empty else None for df in masked_df]
df2['Xmax'] = [np.max(df['X']) if not df.empty else None for df in masked_df]
```

**Old:**

There is likely a faster (i.e. vectorized) way to do this in pandas but I can't figure it out since there are multiple related steps involved for this dataframe transformation. 
However, the following solves your problem:

Input:

```
df1.index = df1.index + pd.DateOffset(years=70)
max_ys = [None] * len(df2)
max_xs = [None] * len(df2)

for ind, row in enumerate(df2.itertuples()):
    mask = (row.start <= df1.index) & (df1.index <= row.end)
    try:
        max_y = max(df1[mask]['Y'])
        max_x = max(df1[mask]['X'])
    except ValueError:
        # Time span doesn't exist in df1
        pass
    else:
        # Found a max val
        max_ys[ind] = max_y
        max_xs[ind] = max_x

df2['Ymax'] = max_ys
df2['Xmax'] = max_xs
```

Output:

```
df2:

                      end                   start      Ymax      Xmax
0 1970-01-01 00:00:10.500 1970-01-01 00:00:10.140       NaN       NaN
1 1970-01-01 00:00:11.180 1970-01-01 00:00:10.700  0.581732 -0.277881
2 1970-01-01 00:00:11.780 1970-01-01 00:00:11.320       NaN       NaN
3 1970-01-01 00:00:12.410 1970-01-01 00:00:11.930       NaN       NaN
4 1970-01-01 00:00:12.900 1970-01-01 00:00:12.500       NaN       NaN
5 1970-01-01 00:00:13.530 1970-01-01 00:00:13.080       NaN       NaN
6 1970-01-01 00:00:14.190 1970-01-01 00:00:13.700       NaN       NaN
7 1970-01-01 00:00:14.810 1970-01-01 00:00:14.310       NaN       NaN
```

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data1 = [
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.679380200', 0.581760, -0.282902, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.720490500', 0.581732, -0.282616, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.762100500', 0.578835, -0.281211, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.801705300', 0.547837, -0.277893, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.846323700', 0.543433, -0.277881, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.889450100', 0.538701, -0.279481, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.894463800', 0.538701, -0.279481, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.896958800', 0.538701, -0.279481, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.897973300', 0.536122, -0.278382, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.924546500', 0.536122, -0.278382, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.936062400', 0.536122, -0.278382, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:10.980179700', 0.536171, -0.278402, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:11.021791100', 0.541177, -0.279649, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:11.059391200', 0.549314, -0.280842, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:11.104509400', 0.559103, -0.281571, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:11.147624400', 0.569963, -0.282739, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:11.187731700', 0.572123, -0.282897, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:11.227337100', 0.574026, -0.283083, 
    '1900-01-01 00:00:11.268947200', 0.574020, -0.283056
]
data2 = [
    '1970-01-01 00:00:10.140', '1970-01-01 00:00:10.500',
    '1970-01-01 00:00:10.700', '1970-01-01 00:00:11.180',
    '1970-01-01 00:00:11.320', '1970-01-01 00:00:11.780',
    '1970-01-01 00:00:11.930', '1970-01-01 00:00:12.410',
    '1970-01-01 00:00:12.500', '1970-01-01 00:00:12.900',
    '1970-01-01 00:00:13.080', '1970-01-01 00:00:13.530',
    '1970-01-01 00:00:13.700', '1970-01-01 00:00:14.190',
    '1970-01-01 00:00:14.310', '1970-01-01 00:00:14.810'
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'timestamp': data1[::3], 'Y': data1[1::3], 'X': data1[2::3]}
)
df1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['timestamp'])
df1 = df1.set_index('timestamp')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'start': data2[::2], 'end': data2[1::2]}
)
df2['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['start'])
df2['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end'])
```